# Autosize rows after calling the autofilter method in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, autosize, autofilter

Maybe this is a easy question but I didn't find info anywhere about it. I'm generating an Excel file and I have a small problem when the file gets generated. The problem is that I call the autofilter method to filter all columns and then I call the autosize method but it seems that is not taking into account the space that the drop down arrows take in the cells.

For instance, I have a column whose header is "AA" and when the file gets generated the column has been shrunk so that I can only see the drop down arrow, not the text of the header. Unfortunately, the values of the column are not long enough to make the column longer when the autosize method is called...

So, does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check your updated Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572879/apache-poi-calling-autosize-after-auto-filter